# I am using com.github.florent37:camerafragment:1.0.8. It woking fine in lollipop but not working in Nougat

Tags: android, android-studio, camera

I am using florent37:cameraFragment for custom camera. It working fine in lollipop but it is not working Nougat version. Please help me out. Thanks in advance

```
 E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
    03-29 12:41:47.722 3773-3863/com.camerasample I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
    03-29 12:41:47.914 3773-3836/com.camerasample I/MediaRecorderJNI: prepare: surface=0x98162800
    03-29 12:41:48.115 3773-3836/com.camerasample E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648
    03-29 12:41:48.115 3773-3836/com.camerasample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: BaseCameraManager
                                                                              Process: com.camerasample, PID: 3773
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.github.florent37.camerafragment.internal.manager.impl.Camera1Manager$4.run(Camera1Manager.java:192)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: you should open a issue on the github repo itself. Also post some relevant code or link to the repo.

Comment: probably something with permissions.

Comment: permission are already given